# Android listen_call_state

Tags: state, call, listen

I made an app that starts a call. If the call drops, the number will automatically be called again. The app no ​​longer works with Android 13. Apparently this is because "LISTEN_CALL_STATE" is outdated and no longer supported. But I can't find such a function in the TelephonyCallback class. Does somebody has any idea?

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(anrufListener, AnrufListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

"listen_call_state" ist deprecated